# how to add command with new line in the variables?

Tags: bash, quoting, variable

as you know when we writing `list=$(ls -l)` all the files added to `$list` like this :

```
total 0 drwx------ 7 mine-pc staff 238 Dec 22 11:32 Applications drwxr-xr-x@ 6 mine-pc staff 204 Jan 11 11:00 Applications (Parallels) drwx------+ 21 mine-pc staff 714 Jan 9 22:33 Desktop drwx------+ 33 mine-pc staff 1122 Jan 7 23:43 Documents drwx------+ 83 mine-pc staff 2822 Jan 11 00:42 Downloads drwx------@ 71 mine-pc staff 2414 Dec 22 01:10 Library drwx------+ 21 mine-pc staff 714 Jan 10 23:48 Movies drwx------+ 4 mine-pc staff 136 Sep 27 17:48 Music drwxr-xr-x 5 mine-pc staff 170 Jan 4 16:25 Parallels drwx------+ 9 mine-pc staff 306 Dec 29 13:06 Pictures drwxr-xr-x+ 5 mine-pc staff 170 Sep 27 15:41 Public
```

how can I insert it to `$list` like this :

```
drwx------   7 mine-pc  staff   238 Dec 22 11:32 Applications
drwxr-xr-x@  6 mine-pc  staff   204 Jan 11 11:00 Applications (Parallels)
drwx------+ 21 mine-pc  staff   714 Jan  9 22:33 Desktop
drwx------+ 33 mine-pc  staff  1122 Jan  7 23:43 Documents
drwx------+ 83 mine-pc  staff  2822 Jan 11 00:42 Downloads
drwx------@ 71 mine-pc  staff  2414 Dec 22 01:10 Library
drwx------+ 21 mine-pc  staff   714 Jan 10 23:48 Movies
drwx------+  4 mine-pc  staff   136 Sep 27 17:48 Music
drwxr-xr-x   5 mine-pc  staff   170 Jan  4 16:25 Parallels
drwx------+  9 mine-pc  staff   306 Dec 29 13:06 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  5 mine-pc  staff   170 Sep 27 15:41 Public
```

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$list` is already in this format. Use quotes:

```
echo "$list"
```

Comment: @Freeman Also see "http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells"